# accessing func in iframe. local to online

Tags: javascript

HI, i got a simple html page, localy with an iframe. the iframe includes a generated page which got a javascript function. i know want to call that function. of course, im getting "permission denied". so since im new to js and all that stuff i dont know if it's actually possible to do that. give me some hints for searching or a nice solution.

i do cal lthe func like: parent.myiframe.myfunc();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the page in the iframe resides on another server / domain. Modern browser do not allow "cross site scripting", see: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Site_Scripting

If possible, move the site in the iframe to the same server. An alternative (workaround) would be to proxy the page on the local server, so that that for the client it seems to be loaded from the same domain.

Edit: This is also called a "Same Origin Policy". You can only call java script functions in a document that is:

- from the same domain (www.mydomain.com)
- from the same subdomain (mail.mydomain.com <- no go!)
- both use the same port (p.Ex.
  accessing a http://... document from
  a http**s**:// document won't work).

There might be another workaround if you have access to the iframe's source:
Change the iframe domain to the same as the outer frame's, by applying:

```
document.domain = "domain.com";
```

in the iframe source (see http://ajaxian.com/archives/how-to-make-xmlhttprequest-calls-to-another-server-in-your-domain for more information).

Also there is a Draft for "Cross-Origin Resource Sharing" (http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) that is already partially implemented in several browser, see: http://www.webdavsystem.com/ajax/programming/cross_origin_requests

Comment: yeah, of course they are on a different domain and i must get it workinglike that. :) thanks

Comment: well basically i think i comes down to whether you have access to the iframe's source / server. If not, there's only one thing you can do:

Comment: i dont have source access but can add some html blocks. its generating a poll so so can add js, html. i've tried that document.domain bevore and it didnt work, but i dont know how it implements this html blocks.

Comment: yeah i wanted to write, the only thing you can do is: proxy the (iframe source) site.

Comment: maybe somethign wiht jsonp, passing a var would be enough.

Comment: well, do you control the iframe? What is the purpose of the iframe? What is the purpose of that function inside the iframe? Could one design the application different? ...